# Arduino Pow() and Armstrong number problem

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

This is the code I want to run. I tried many things like I found a solution with math.h doing ceil() but I really want to understand why this does not work even when i do something like

`pow((int)j, 3) + pow((int)d, 3) + pow((int)s, 3)`

where j is then 3, d is 5 and s is 1;
if i where to just do

`pow(3,3) + pow(5,3) + pow(1, 3)`
The condition would then be true.

I know that sum is of type double and `Serial.println(sum)` says 153.00 which is i suppose `152.999999` something like that but how does `int j = 3;` differ from just placin 3 into `pow()` I checked binary data and j is in fact `0011` d is `0101` and s is `0001` with `Serial.println(j, BIN);`

```cpp
int n = 100;
float j, d, s;
double sum;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  delay(100);
  if (n >= 100 && n < 154) {
    j = n % 10; // 153 % 10 = 3;
    d = n / 10 % 10; // 15 % 10 = 5;
    s = n / 100; // 153 / 100 = 1;

    sum = pow(j, 3) + pow (d, 3) + pow(s, 3);

    if (sum == n) {
      Serial.println(n);
    }

    n++;
  }
}
```

If I find some typos here I will correct myself I just typed this into here not copy pasting it :)

Answer (score 0):

> how does `int j = 3;` differ from just placing 3 into `pow()`

`pow(int, int)` is a different function from `pow(float, float)`.  The *quality* of `pow(float, float)` is apparently weak enough here to only get *close* to the mathematically correct answer.  C/C++ does not specify the required closeness for such functions.

Could round the `pow(float, float)` answer or simply, for exact math problems, avoid floating point math.

---

Keep in mind a better result implementation may come at the cost of time performance.  You often get what you pay for.

Answer (score 0):

Really, if you are using pow to raise something to the power of 3, you're probably doing it wrong ;)

```cpp
template<typename T> T sqr(const T x) { return x*x; }
template<typename T> T cube(const T x) { return x*x*x; }
```

But yeah, pow returns an *approximation* to the power, so if you are using floats (as you are here for j, d, and s), then you should expect some rounding error, and handle that accordingly.

If you are only interested in doing integer calculations here, maybe change the type to int?

```cpp
int j, d, s;
```